# Python BeautifulSoup filter data while parsing a URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to parse these on daily basis, before market open and I successfully get the list, but now i wanted to add additional filter for "strong buys" and "Volume" > 5000000 from the underlying url data `https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-gainers/`

**full code below**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-gainers/"
siteinfo = requests.get(url)

i = 0
content = siteinfo.content
html = content
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")

doneList = []
for link in parsed_html.find_all('a'):
    a = link.get('href')
    if "symbol" in str(a) and "-" in str(a):
        if i < 25:
            i += 1
        else:
            x = a.split("-")
            x = x[1].split("/")
            doneList.append(x[0])
            i += 1

print(doneList)
```

Comment: Paste the error log too. Also a way to solve this is to print what you've parsed and also print what you're getting after split. The error might not be with code but with the data you're are parsing.

Comment: Post the full stack trace please-- it includes useful info like line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you're probably better off using pandas w/ multiple conditions and a filter:

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.tradingview.com/markets/stocks-usa/market-movers-gainers/'
df = pd.read_html(url)[0]

#create a helper function as a filter - it returns a series of boolean values
def filter_out(row):
    #Unnamed: 4 is the buy recommendation and the next one is volume
    if 'Strong' in row['Unnamed: 4'] and 'M' in row['Unnamed: 5']:
        #since you're using a 5M volume as condition, you have to check for its existence:
        if (int(row['Unnamed: 5'].split('.')[0])>5):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
#use the boolean values to filter the dataframe:
bulls = df.apply(filter_out, axis=1)
df[bulls]
```

Output (pardon the formatting):

```
     Unnamed: 0            Unnamed: 1   Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  Unnamed: 10
0   M MRIN Marin Software Incorporated  7.50    96.85%  3.69    Strong Buy  263.387M    41.786M     —   -1.59   162.00  Technology Services
2   NTLA Intellia Therapeutics, Inc.    133.43  50.21%  44.60   Strong Buy  21.740M     6.054B  —   -2.46   312.00  Health Technology
3   A AUUD Auddia Inc.  5.89    43.66%  1.79    Strong Buy  36.281M     46.296M     —   —   11.00   Technology Services
```

etc. You can then change columns names or do other processing.

EDIT:

To get only the tickers of these companies use:

```
ticks = df[bulls]['Unnamed: 0'].to_list()
for tick in ticks:
    print(tick.split('  ')[-2])
```

Output:

```
MRIN
NTLA
AUUD
WTT
```

etc.

Comment: Excellent. How do I just print the stock Ticker symbol here? Also is there a way to add additional filer for "strong buys". Thank you

Comment: @stackuser I'm not sure I understand the first part of your question. As to the second, you can add as many filters as you need. If you have something specific in mind, you should probably post another question based on this one.

Comment: Thank you, In the output. I just wanted to output one column Stock Ticker symbol.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, exit code 0 means there was no error in your code. Thus, the index out of range error must be from the print statement `print(e)` (exception handled).

Looking at your code, this is the most vulnerable part for list index out of range error.

```
quote = get_quote(stock)
```

I don't know the inner mechanism of get_quote, but I guess this is where the error occured.

Comment: Thank you. Ok I took all the unnecessary complication and modified the scripts as above, can you plz take a look and suggest on how I can further filter the data, while parsing it